# Icon command does not show up in VScode extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am writing a VSCode extension and I'd like to add an icon to my commands.
But the icon does not show up neither in command palette nor the editor context menu.
Am I missing something here?

This is how I defined my command in package.json:

```
...
    "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "myCommand",
        "title": "title",
        "icon": "assets/icon.svg"
      },
...
    "menus": {
      "commandPalette": [
        {
          "command": "myCommand"
        },
...
     "editor/context": [
        {
          "command": "myCommand",
          "group": "mine@1",
          "when": "editorHasSelection"
        },
...
```

Comment: Icons only show up where they are supported. Menus and the command drop down do not support them. You see them in sidebar sections and toolbars.